# Differences in calculations should be due to differences in environment?

Tags: coordinate-systems, observers, covariance

Lisa Randall in her book Warped Passages writes,

> "A very reasonable thing to expect from physical laws is that they should be the same for everyone.
>   No one could blame us for questioning their validity and utility if people in different countries or
>   sitting on moving trains or flying on an airplane experienced different physical laws. Physical laws
>   should be fundamental and hold true for any observer. *Any differences in calculations should be
>   due to differences in environment, not the physical laws*."

What does she mean when she says "*Any differences in calculations should be
due to differences in environment, not the physical laws*." Can one explain with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She simply means that there needs to be a physical difference in the environment to have differences in the behaviour of phyiscal systems. For an example, supposed Newtonian mechanics was a fundamental theory of nature. Then the universal law is
$$ F = ma. $$
Suppose further the only thing in existence are charged particles moving in external electromagnetic fields (no backreaction of the moving charges on the fields), so the universal law is
$$ m\ddot{x} = q (E(x) + \dot{x}\times B(x)),$$
that is, the equation of motion under a Lorentz force. This law holds true for all observers in our hypothetical and very simple (and potentially inconsistent) universe. Different "calculations" arise from different values of $E(x)$ and $B(x)$ at different points, but the law itself never changes.